# Has this patent been issued?

Tags: reissue

In reference to the patent: [US20090237236](https://www.google.com/patents/US20090237236)

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear so. The current status on PAIR indicates that it was abandoned whilst it was pending for failure to respond to an office action on 24th Feb 2011.

EDIT: link to the US PTO Public Patent Application Information Retrieval (PAIR) website is below:

https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

I have attached a screenshot evidencing the current status.[image]

Comment: Adding a link to the US Public Pair site would make this answer a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If it has been granted it will say "Grant" in the "Publication type" heading.

Applications that are subsequently granted will link to the grant document.  As an example:

> Publication number:   [CA2128634 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2128634A1?dq=magic%20the%20gathering)
>   Publication type:   **Application**
>   Application number: CA 2128634
>   Publication date:   Dec 23, 1995
>   Filing date:    Jul 22, 1994
>   Priority date:  Jun 22, 1994
>   Also published as:  CA2128634C, US5662332, USRE37957
>
> Publication number:    [CA2128634 C](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2128634C?dq=magic%20the%20gathering)
>   Publication type:   **Grant**
>   Application number: CA 2128634
>   Publication date:   Sep 27, 2005
>   Filing date:    Jul 22, 1994
>   Priority date:  Jun 22, 1994
>   Also published as   CA2128634A1, US5662332, USRE37957

- The example you asked about is listed as an application, and the links to alternate publications are both also only applications

To verify 100% you may want to check the official Patent Agency databases, such as [WIPO](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf) or [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/search-patents).  *[Note that the USPTO database is notoriously difficult to navigate, so in some ways it may be less reliable from a result standpoint than Google Patents.]*

Another method would be to do a followup search by inventor name to see if there is a grant for them on a similar invention (i.e. to eliminate the possibility of error based on lack of link to the grant in the application page.)

Comment: I find the US Public Pair site the most reliable for US patents. The problem with your answer, is that if someone goes to Google patents and searches an application number they get the application. You have to look for an "also published as" link to find the possible granted patent. In any case Google patents has its problems. The Lens is more reliable.